# How do you find all values of x where f(x)=g(x) using maple?

Tags: functions, maple

I'm using maple and I've been given two functions,

$$f(x)=5^x$$
$$g(x)=x^5$$
And I've been asked to use maple to find all values of x where $$f(x)=g(x)$$ but using maple. What is the way to enter this into maple properly to get the output of all x values where the above is true?

edit: I am using Maple 2016

Comment: Hint: find the roots of $f-g$.

Comment: you can also use the LambertW function

Comment: it's also depend on which Version do you have

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/solve)

Comment: solve(5^x=x^5,x);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kernelopts(version);

   Maple 2016.2, X86 64 LINUX, Jan 13 2017, Build ID 1194701

f:=5^x:
g:=x^5:

Student:-Calculus1:-Roots(f-g, x=-infinity .. infinity);

                     5 LambertW(-1/5 ln(5))
                  [- ----------------------, 5]
                             ln(5)

evalf(%);

                        [1.764921914, 5.]

# Alternatively,

solve( {f-g, x>-infinity, x<infinity} );

                             5 LambertW(-1/5 ln(5))
             {x = 5}, {x = - ----------------------}
                                     ln(5)

evalf([%]);

                  [{x = 5.}, {x = 1.764921915}]

# Or, more crudely
plot(f-g, x=-4..6, view=-1..1);

fsolve(f-g, x=1..3);

                           1.764921915

fsolve(f-g, x=4..6);

                           5.000000000
```